# Spiralling Scroller with Dynamic Path Sizing

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, scrollview

I have a list of items in a server. These items have scores and the scores correspond to the size of their view (a circle).  I would like to depict these items with the largest circle in the center and each successively smaller circle wrapping around it, spiralling smaller and smaller.

Once I achieve this I would like to set it to a scroll.  A scroll up will add each successively larger item to the center of the spiral and eventually spiralling down and away and vice versa.

The sizing of these objects I have performed already.

Here's my methodology:  Native Swift doesn't have anything to help me layout-wise here to my knowledge.  V/HStack won't help and neither will ScrollView.  Essentially my understanding is that I should create a path that calculates its spiral based on the sizes of the items and these items should use .offset to position themselves on the path.  Using a DragGesture, I can attach a @State variable to determine how far down the path each item is.

This is by far the most complex UI I've attempted so anything to get me down the right path is appreciated.

Edit 1:
Here is the ideal UI:

[image]

Comment: A few images of your **goal** would help.

Comment: Added. Let me know if that is not sufficient.

Comment: OK - not quite clear what you want to happen... are you going to start with only the center circle (1)... drag down on it... it shrinks as it reveals the next center circle (2) and stops at the bottom.. next drag shrinks and moves (2) to the bottom, revealing circle (3) and shrinks+moves (1) up and right? and so on?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I've played around with this a little bit... You said *"...the scores correspond to the size of their view..." How close is your drawing to what you want? That is, the circles are not decreasing in radius at a specific rate... their sizes are related to specific values? So, circles 6 & 7 may be the same size as each other, 8 & 9 the same, 10 / 11 / 12 the same, etc?

Comment: Correct, so 6&7 may be the same size, and then the value of 7 increases and its size increases as a result. I've got a linear scroll working in this fashion.  The size of the smallest is itsValue/maxValue where maxValue is the value corresponding to the largest score. As I scroll up, a zoomValue changes by calculating the inverse of that relationship as the zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are various ways to approach this.

Dragging the "top" view down using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` - and Scaling it during the drag - is pretty straight-forward. Getting the "already dragged" views to animate around the center is a bit tougher.

One approach is to use a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and creating Key Frames for the positions around the arc.

Additional advantages to that include fewer calculations (set scaling and position key frames in `.began` state) as well as being able to "scrub" through the animation.

I put together a little demo that ended up looking like this:

[image]

You can play with the source code here: https://github.com/DonMag/OrbitDrag

Comment: This is huge! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.